# How to change blank fields to null in express js

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser, express-validator

I want to get all request body params as null if param is blank. Is there any way in the express js.

```
{
  username: " ",
  password: ""
}
```

// Get it as

```
{
  username: null,
  password: null
}
```

Comment: BTW , commas are missing between the object elements in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to use this function below:

```js
let objects = {
    username: ' ',
    password: '',
    testing: [
      {
        id: ' ',
        testing: 'testing'
      }
    ],
    obj: {
      key: ' ',
      value: 'value'
    }
}

function setEmptyToNull(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
            obj[key].map(o => {
                if (typeof o === 'object') {
                    setEmptyToNull(o);
                }
            })
        } else if(typeof obj[key] ==='string') {
          if(obj[key].trim() === '') {
            obj[key] = null;
          }  
        } else if(typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
          setEmptyToNull(obj[key]);
        }
    });
    return obj;
}

console.log(setEmptyToNull(objects));
```

Now, **if you want to use in your express application**, then you can set that function in your custom `middleware`. It's will looks like this code below:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if(req.body) {
    setEmptyToNull(req.body);
  };
  next();
});
```

After you set your custom `middleware`, now each `value` of key in your `req.body`, if it's `' '` then will be set to `null`.

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

in a most simplest way (if you want to mutate the original object itself)

```
let obj = {username:'' , password:''}
for(i in obj){
    if(obj[i] === '')
        obj[i] = null
}
```